# How does forEach apply the lambda expression to an array if it's an abstract method?

Tags: java, foreach, interface, iterable

```
List<String> friends = Arrays.asList("Brian", "Nate", "Neal", "Sara");
friends.forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
```

I'm studying java and I found this example, i just put it in a main and it printed the array normally, so my question is:

In my understanding `name -> System.out.println(name)` is a lambda expression used to quickly implement a printing function, but I wonder how does `forEach` apply it to every element of the array?It is a method of the `Iterable` interface, therefore...empty, so where is the code telling to apply the print to each name in the array?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher `Iterable.forEach` is a *default method*, so there is an implementation in the interface (may be overridden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns `ArrayList` in the current implementation, which has an implementation of `forEach` iterating with a mundane `for-loop` applying the lambda to each element. It overrides (through some layers of inheritance) and implements `Iterable.forEach`. It also extends `List` of course. From java.util.ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; modCount == expectedModCount && i < size; i++)
    action.accept(elementAt(es, i));
```

From java.util.Arrays:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is default method from [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) interface and default implementation is just enhanced for loop calling `Consumer` for each element

```
for (T t : this)
     action.accept(t);
```

> Performs the given action for each element of the Iterable until all elements have been processed or the action throws an exception. Unless otherwise specified by the implementing class, actions are performed in the order of iteration (if an iteration order is specified). Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.